# How to debug character set difference with document class change?

Tags: xetex, symbols, document-classes, characters

I'm trying to use an agda package to compile to latex, and am getting the below error when I make a seemingly insignificant change to the literate agda file (see https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.1/tools/literate-programming.html#literate-agda-tex)

```
Missing character: There is no ℓ in font DejaVu Serif Italic/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
```

If I use the following, i get the correct `ell` display, but it goes off the page.

```
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}
```

If I change the class to what follows, I get a decent document which displays all the code on the page, but doesn't process `ell` with the above error.

```
\documentclass[xetex]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
```

What accounts for this change?  To view the display in pdf format, please see
https://github.com/wmacmil/latexAgdaShowase

Edit:
For reference, here is are the rest of the imports

```
\usepackage{agda}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
% Alternatively:
% \setmathfont{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% \newunicodechar{ℓ}{\ensuremath{\mathnormal\ell}}


\begin{document}
```

Comment: Uncomment the `\newunicodechar` command that sets `ℓ` active. Alternatively, you could import it from DejaVu Math TeX Gyre.

Comment: I then get `! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 \newunicodechar
                    {ℓ}{\ensuremath{\mathnormal\ell}}

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.15 \newunicodechar{ℓ
                      }{\ensuremath{\mathnormal\ell}}
Missing character: There is no ℓ in font DejaVu Serif/OT:script=latn;language=d
`

Comment: and then further down `Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  xelatex: Command for 'xelatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'Morphism1.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
make: *** [Makefile:14: latex/Morphism1.pdf] Error 12
`

Comment: `\newunicodechar` needs the newunicodechar package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good catch!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , that worked, feel free to turn that into an answer!